# Expandable listview - Highlight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, expandablelistview

I have used a customised expandable listview in my application.

I have used individual xml for parent and child rows. I have set the color of both these xml's as white. Now, the issue i have is, the expandable listview is not getting highlighted in orange color on clicking a parent or child row.

How can  I accomplish this?

Any help in this regard would be well appreciated.

Best Regards,
Rony

Comment: dude i think there is some problem in your layout.. check your child and group parent layout. i think it wil work.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) to specify an alternate color for pressed views (assuming that when you changed the views to white, you did so by giving them a white drawable for the background).  Without seeing the XML/code, though, I can't say for sure.

Alternatively, you may actually be able to use a [color state list](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).